# Spring Boot - override OAuth client configuration at startup

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth, openid

I have a Spring Boot application with the following config:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@Configuration
public class DemoApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

 @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .antMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/","/appConfig", "/login/**", "/webjars/**")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/"))
            .and().logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
            .and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());

    } 
...
}
```

In the resources, I have an application.yml, which contains the client configuration:

```
security:
      oauth2:
        client:
          clientId: @keycloak.client.id@
          clientSecret: @keycloak.client.secret@
          accessTokenUri: https://@keycloak.host@:@keycloak.port@/auth/realms/@keycloak.realm@/protocol/openid-connect/token
          userAuthorizationUri: https://@keycloak.host@:@keycloak.port@/auth/realms/@keycloak.realm@/protocol/openid-connect/auth
          authenticationScheme: header
          clientAuthenticationScheme: header
        resource:
          userInfoUri: https://@keycloak.host@:@keycloak.port@/auth/realms/@keycloak.realm@/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
```

So far it works fine, but I have to set the clientSecret (and maybe also other properties) programatically at startup of the application as the client is registered with the OpenId server also at startup, so the secret is only known after the registration is done.

I did some experimentation with the AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter to create an inMemory client, but if it's also added to the filter chain, the application does not start at all:

```
- Bean method 'userInfoRestTemplateFactory' not loaded because @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration'
```

Any ideas how to set the clientSecret at startup from code instead of hardcoding it in the application.yml?

Answer (score 0):

These properties go to a `ResourceServerProperties` object. What if you create it yourself:

```
@Bean
public ResourceServerProperties ouathResource() {
   // read from somewhere
   return new ResourceServerProperties( id, secret)
}
```

The presence of this bean could suppress the automatic creation of other beans, in which case they will have to be created manually too.

Comment: Thanks! Did it, and marked it with @Primary, so spring knows which one of the 2 beans to use. But this way the clientId and secret is not set at all.

Comment: If you replace `//read from somewhere` with code that sets `id` and `secret`?

Comment: Yes, of course - i hardcoded id and secret to the constructor just to be sure, I would do the dynamic reading later if it works like this.
I'm asking myself, if it's not too "late" in the filter chain to create this bean...